# contr.Sum and standard error in R

Tags: r, regression, anova, contrasts

I want to fit a linear model in R with a categorical variable that takes 3 possible levels. My goal is to check the effect of each level against a global mean, therefore I use contr.sum as contrasts.

When I look at the coefficients, I can see that R returns only two of them (I suppose that is because internally the 3 levels are mapped to 2 dummy variables).

But I am interested in assessing the effect of all the levels. Now, I know that the effect of the missing level is just minus the sum of the other two, but what about the standard error? Is there a way to get the standard error associated to the missing coefficient? I.e. How can I know the error of the estimated difference between the missing level and the global mean?

P.S. The data are not balanced.

Answer (score 0):

After three days thinking about it, a solution came to my mind just after posting the question here :)

Basically if $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ are the coefficients of the three levels, then R will fit only $a_1$ and $a_2$, returning the standard errors $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. To find $a_3$:
$$
a_3 = -a_1-a_2 \\
\sigma_3^2 = \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2 + 2cov_{12}
$$
where the covariance can be extracted from the fitted model using the function `vcov`.